# How to load a Pandas DataFrame into TensorFlow for efficient batch training?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

More specifically, I want to load batches of different feature groups from that DataFrame, and I have no idea how to do this!

Let's say I have DataFrame consisting of features `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I have a placeholder in my TensorFlow code for a `batch_size x 1` tensor that's supposed to represent feature `A`, and another placeholder in my TensorFlow code for a `batch_size x 2` tensor that's supposed to represent BOTH features `B` and `C`.

Of course, I can just iterate across the Pandas DataFrame and use `feed_dict` to do batch training, but that would be inefficient.

How would I load the DataFrame into TensorFlow's efficient data processing pipelines such that I can feed it as desired into placeholder 1 and placeholder 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to TensorFlow 2.0 documentation, it is advisable to use: `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.

The full tutorial is available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe

NOTE: You may need to refactor your code as `tf.placeholder()` is not compatible with eager execution. I would personally eliminate it completely from my codebase.